# Double request header in a single HTTP request

Tags: ios, http, http-headers

The problematic requests look like this

```
POST /api/v2/users/push HTTP/1.1 
Host: glowing.com 
Content-Type: application/json 
Accept: */* 
Connection: keep-alive 
Cookie: _ga=GA1.2.840810247.1459550932 
User-Agent: Glow/201605261852 CFNetwork/758.4.3 Darwin/15.5.0 
Accept-Language: en-us 
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate 
Content-Length: 402 

POST /api/v2/users/push HTTP/1.1 
Host: glowing.com 
Content-Type: application/json 
Accept: */* 
Connection: keep-alive 
Cookie: _ga=GA1.2.840810247.1459550932 
User-Agent: Glow/201605261852 CFNetwork/758.4.3 Darwin/15.5.0 
Accept-Language: en-us 
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate 
Content-Length: 402 

{"app_version":"3.0.2","locale":"en_GB","log_list":...}
```

The header appeared twice in the request, and that causes our server raising errors when parsing the request. Some other notes about this problem

- Our app has both iOS and Android client, which sends HTTP requests to the same server. And we only encounter this problem in iOS client. So it's more likely a client issue.
- Our server gets millions of requests per day, and the problem only happens about 20-30 times.

So far I don't have any clues how to debug this issue. Any suggestions are welcome.

UPDATE:

I'm not sure whether the problem is in our iOS code, but here is the code we use for sending loggings to our server. And this double-header issue happens occasionally with this network request

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [@{@"log_list": logList} mutableCopy];
params[@"app_version"] = [Utils appVersion];
params[@"device_id"] = [Utils UUID];
params[@"locale"] = [Utils localeString];
params[@"model"] = [Utils modelString];


NSData *requestData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:params options:0 error:nil];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.apiURL]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setTimeoutInterval:LOGGING_REQUEST_TIMEOUT];
[request setHTTPBody:requestData];
[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:error];
```

Comment: How do you create the request? Do you use any libraries (Alamofire, AFNetworking)?

Comment: For this specific app, we're using native NSMutableURLRequest and NSURLConnection to make network request. But we have other 3 apps with the same double-header problem, 2 of them uses AFNetworking, and 1 of them uses Alamofire (that one is written in Swift)

Comment: How do you invoke your method? Also I think the problems might be because of thread concurrency or the last line, where you don't use sendSynchronousRequest's result or setting parameter to nil(just a theory)

Comment: Just try adding a log before and after the request is made and see how many times it happens. Also since you are using Synchronous calls there might be some other thread that is interfering with this thread. If the issue is overlapping then the only way to handle this is to put the calls that are overlapping into separate threads.

Comment: Just a case, do you have chance to use NSURLSession? Because NSURLConnection is deprecated.

Comment: Cross check with - by configuring your default NSURLSession and try to use NSURLSession data api's .  I have never had header issues with NSURLConnection and I have written my own wrapper API's . Maybe you should also check on the server side code.

Answer (score 1):

I have never had header issues with NSURLConnection and I have written my own wrapper API's around NSURLConnection. You can also verify by printing your header fields as shown below.  You can also cross check with - by configuring your default NSURLSession and try to use [NSURLSession data api's](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/) . Maybe you should also check on the server side code. If there is really an issue with your code, do please post your findings. Would be helpful for our fellow developers.

```
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://your URL here"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: url];
NSHTTPURLResponse *response;
[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse: &response error: nil];
if ([response respondsToSelector:@selector(allHeaderFields)]) {
NSDictionary *dictionary = [response allHeaderFields];
NSLog([dictionary description]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a shot in the dark, but this might help you debug the issue.

Make it so the server replies with Connection: close rather than Connection: keep-alive.

I think there might be a case when certain clients try to make a connection which times out before the server replies, so they try the request again thinking the connection is still valid.

Try returning Connection: close for that particular endpoint and verify if the issue keeps appearing

Comment: I think it's worth trying. But in production environment, we're using AWS ELB, and there seems no easy way to set "Connection: close" header instead of "Connection: keep-alive" in the response. In development environment, we're not using ELB, but in the meantime the occurrence of this issue is really small (one instance every few months).